# fetch set plugin from CodeArtifacts using sbt fail

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin, aws-codeartifact

I used this explanation how to publish and fetch SBT libraries from CodeArtifacts:

[Publish artifact to AWS CodeArtifact with sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620633/publish-artifact-to-aws-codeartifact-with-sbt)

my issue is that one of the things I want to publish is not a library, its a plugin, so I used the same explanation, except that I have all the plugin setup (I used frog before and it was working fine, just changed to publish to CodeArtifacts instead based on this explanation)

the publish went fine, I went and took this line:
[image]

cause that's what I have there and inserted inside the plugin code:
`addSbtPlugin("com.mycompany" % "sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0" % "0.0.41")`

and when I tried to fetch I get "not found".

am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the suffix `_2.12_1.0`:

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.mycompany" % "sbt-plugin" % "0.0.41")
```

The suffix is automatically managed by SBT.

*FYI, `2.12` is the Scala version of the plugin, `1.0` is the SBT major version*

Comment: dosent work still, its also how its written in codeartifacts

Comment: What's the error with this?